# Create a duplicate record based on a condition

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I need to write a shell script where I have to create a duplicate record based on a condition and then change the value in a column of the new row which will be created.

I am trying to create a duplicate record based on a condition and then replace on column in the duplicate row.

**Example:**

Input will be

**Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,COl5**

```
1234,abcd,abcd,wxyz,USD
2345,abcd,abcd,wxyz,USD
3456,abcd,abcd,wxyz,EUR
```

If the last column ie; col5 is EUR, then one more row should be created with change in column value.

**Output should be**

**Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5**

```
1234,abcd,abcd,wxyz,USD
2345,abcd,abcd,wxyz,USD
3456,abcd,abcd,wxyz,EUR
3456,abcd,abcd,wxyz,AUD
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways:

- awk

  ```
  awk -F, '{print; if($NF=="EUR"){$NF="AUD"; OFS=",";print}}' file
  ```

  That is checking the last field (`$NR`) to check another field, change `$NR` to `$N`, where N is the number you want to check (e.g `$3` for the 5th field).
- Perl

  ```
  perl -pe '$_.= "$1AUD\n" if /(.*)EUR$/' file
  ```

  This one uses a lot of Perl shorthand that is kind of harder to explain. You can write the same thing like this:

  ```
  perl -e 'while(<>){if(/(.*)EUR$/){print "$_","$1AUD\n"} else {print "$_"}}'
  ```

for each line of the input file

Comment: The `perl` one-liner will print the new record (with `AUD`) before the old one (with `EUR`)

Comment: Thanks Joseph, Just to add, How can I change the position of condition column, FOr example if the condition column is Col3 instead of Col5.

Comment: @user47766 see updated answer, the gawk one is easy to change, the Perl on is a bit more complex.

Comment: @user47766 Are we still talking about substituting `EUR` with `AUD` but a in a different column or will the patterns be different in this case?

Answer (score 2):

using `sed`:

```
 sed -e 's|^\(.*\),EUR$|\1,EUR\r\1,AUD|'
```

Answer (score 2):

A Perl alternative

```
perl -ne 'print;print if s/EUR\Z/AUD/' your_file
```

If you want to make the modifications to the file in place, just add the `-i` switch:

```
perl -ni -e 'print;print if s/EUR\Z/AUD/' your_file
```